# How can I switch between Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters with kubectl?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

From the Google Cloud Shell, when I run `kubectl` I am running it on the GKE cluster (`cluster-1`) from my previous project (`my-project-1`). I would like to run it on the gke cluster (`cluster-2`) in my new project (`my-project-2`).

How can I update my context to use the new cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works this:

1. Login

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

2. Switch to the project

```
gcloud config set project <your-project-name>
```

3. List available clusters

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

4. Get the cluster credentials

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --region <cluster-region>
```

Then I was able to switch the context of `kubectl`

Answer (score 4):

1. To check what cluster you are currently using:

   ```
   kubectl config current-context
   ```
2. To check what clusters you have configured:

   ```
   kubectl config get-contexts
   ```
3. To switch, you have two options:

   (Option 1) If you don't have the cluster you to switch to configured, run:

   ```
   gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --region <cluster-region> --project <project>
   ```

   (Option 2) Use kubectl to switch context, get `<name>` from step 2:

   ```
   kubectl config use-context <name>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the commands that work for me when I want to switch between clusters:

1. Check current cluster:

   ```
   kubectl config current-context
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   my-project-1_us-central1_cluster-1
   ```
2. Switch to a different cluster (replace `$CLUSTER_NAME`, `$REGION`, and `$PROJECT_NAME` with your values):

   ```
   gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --region $REGION --project $PROJECT_NAME
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-2 --region us-central1 --project my-project-2
   ```
3. Confirm you have switched clusters by re-running the `current-context` command

   ```
   kubectl config current-context
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   my-project-2_us-central1_cluster-2
   ```